# Get _meta of model through relationship

Tags: python, django

I have two models. I would like to pass one of the models to a function, and then have the function traverse the ManyToManyField to display the related model's fields.

```
class Email(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    time_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='emails')

class Contact(models.Model):
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

The end result would be something like:

```
>>> get_fields_of_related_model(Email)
{'recipients': {'email_address': 'EmailField',
                'contact_name': 'CharField'}}
>>> get_fields_of_related_model(Contact)
{'emails': {'subject': 'CharField',
            'body': 'TextField',
            'time_sent': 'DateTimeField',
            'recipients': 'ManyToManyField'}}
```

Comment: Did you mean `recipients` field being an M2M to `Contact` and not `Email`?

Comment: I think I've set it up as I wanted. Running the function on either function should return the fields of all M2M relationships' models as a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Currently `Email` is not related to `Contact` as far as I can see

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov Goodness me, you're right. You have a better eye than mine. I've fixed that and thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access m2m fields like this:

```
Email._meta.local_many_to_many
```

Then you can get related model fields like this:

```
Email._meta.local_many_to_many[0].related_model._meta.fields
```

Spitballing how the function would look like:

```
def get_fields_of_related_model(model):
    return {m2m_field.name: m2m_field.related_model._meta.fields for m2m_field in model._meta.local_many_to_many}
```

Comment: Pointing out related_model is what really did it for me. Thank you.